# Using my registration form from the form.py file i want to authenticate the user. First he will register and using that data he has to login

Tags: django

```
    My models.py file

    class Registration(models.Model):

        user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null = True, blank = True)
        email = models.EmailField()
        password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        #password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label='Password')
        #passwordrepeat = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label='Repeat Password')
        gender_choice = (('M', 'Male'),
                        ('F', 'Female'),
                        )
        # Limit the choices for the size field to the above given choices
        gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=gender_choice)
        address = models.TextField()

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.user_name

    my form.py file

    class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Registration
            widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }

    view.py file

    def user_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
            return render(request, "complete.html")
        else:
            form = RegistrationForm()
        return render(request, "user_register.html", { 'form' : form })

    login application is

    form.py file

    class LoginForm(forms.Form):
        username = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label="Password")

    view.py

    def login(request):

        if request.method == "POST":
            form =  LoginForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                username = form.cleaned_data['username']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password']        
                user = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
                if user:
                    if user.is_authenticated():
                        auth.login(request,user) 



        else:        
            form = LoginForm()

        return render(request,'login.html',{'form':form})

    def logout(request):
        auth.logout(request)  
        messages.success(request,'Logged out')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

now i want to use register model data to user get login not default user data which django provides for ex: admin

I dont want to use default django authentication.
So please help me what i have to do for using the registered data for login. its like sim ple register and login using the same data

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you inherit the default login, with your customized login? Thats what I do all the time.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Registration(User):
     #Other fields than username, email, password, or any field not present in the default user model
```

This is the same as you have described, and you can use the django-login functionality with this.

This model now contains all the fields of the default User model, along with whatever you need to include in addition.

Comment: You shouldn't inherit from User these days, you should inherit from AbstractUser (or AbstractBaseUser).

Comment: Still its not working. Still its taking the default user login. Ex admin.  not taking data from the registered user.

Comment: @GauravWagh: This actually combines your registered user, with the default user. This is how you are supposed to do it. The Registration model INHERITS the default user model

Comment: @AswinMurugesh auth.User is not an abstract class. So inheriting from it creates a multi-table inheritance: some fields will be in the original auth_user table, and some will be in the new Registration table, so you'll get unnecessary joins and extra DB queries. Inheriting from AbstractUser avoids this scenario, and you can then set `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` to the new model to avoid creating the auth_user model altogether.